# deque.at No Maching Function

Tags: c++, deque

I am trying to deque (a string element) from a deque data structure. But I am getting and error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string::basic_string(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<std::array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 1> >, std::arraystd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 1> >::value_type&)’
> 26 |  string record = (string)records.at(0);

```
deque<array<string, 1>>     records;
string data("hello this is 1st record");
array<string, 1>        buffer{data};
records.push_back(buffer);

string record = (string)records.at(0); //error is reported at this line
printf("%s\n", record.c_str());
```

Can someone please give me a hint what I am doing wrongly.
As background, I have to cache the last 100 text messages, so I am using deque for this purpose.

Comment: Your deque doesn't hold strings; it holds `array<string,1>`. And force-casting `(string)records.at(0);` isn't the way to try and fix that. `string record = records.at(0).at(0);` will get your string, though I cannot fathom why you're using `array<string,1>` as queue elements in the first place.

Comment: `records.at(0)` is not a string, it is a `array<string,1>`. Don't use C casts, they are evil

Comment: why do you use an `array` when it can only hold a single element?

Comment: Using C casts like `(string)` is almost always an indicator that you're doing something wrong

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do with `(string)records.at(0)`) you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: And why do you have a deque of array of a *single* string? What problem is the `array<string, 1>` supposed to solve?

Comment: you can see I am a newbie, Thanks all, for the comments, the problem is solved by your comments. Regards All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear why you are using `array` as elements. The value returned from `at` is not a string but an array.

```
deque<array<string, 1>>     records;
string data("hello this is 1st record");
array<string, 1>        buffer{data};
records.push_back(buffer);

string record = records.at(0)[0];
                        ^^ get first element in deque
                              ^^ get first element in array
```

Do not use c-style casts (`(string)...`). They are almost always wrong (and when they are not, they should be replaced with a safer C++ cast). If you do not use the array (why? when it only holds a single element?) the code is

```
deque<string>     records;
string data("hello this is 1st record");
records.push_back(data);

string record = records.at(0);
                        ^^ get first element in deque
```